# Assignment made inside a thread not visible in another thread

Tags: c++, multithreading

I'm trying to trigger the execution of a worker thread via a `std::condition_variable` and a bool `condition`. The worker waits for the notification and starts to work if the `condition` is true. After the work `condition` is set to false. Additionally there is a mutex to synchronize.

In the main thread, a loop checks if `condition` is false and if it is the case the `condition` gets set to true and the condition_variable is notified.

When running this code I would expect, that the output would "spam" *woke up* and *working*, but it is executed only once, because somehow the assignment to `condition` in `thread_function()` isn't visible in the main thread / is lost inside the worker thread. The output says, that it is false after the assignment, when going through it with the debugger it is false after the assignment, but when the if in the main thread is evaluated, it is true again.

Am I missing something?

I tried this in VS2013 and VS2012 and I tried to replace the `bool` with a `std::atomic_bool`, but that didn't help either.

```
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <iostream>
#include <atomic>

bool condition;
std::mutex condition_mutex;
std::condition_variable cv;

void thread_function() {
    while (true) {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(condition_mutex);
        cv.wait(lock);
        std::cout << "woke up\n";
        if (condition) {
            // do stuff
            std::cout << "thread working\n";
            condition = false;
            std::cout << "thread: " << (condition ? "true" : "false") << "\n";
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    condition = false;
    std::thread t(&thread_function);

    while (true) {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(condition_mutex);
//        std::cout << "main: " << (condition ? "true" : "false") << "\n";
        if (!condition) {
            condition = true;
            cv.notify_one();
        }
    }    
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should place the lock outside of the while loop:

```
void thread_function() {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(condition_mutex);
    while (true) {
        cv.wait(lock);
        std::cout << "woke up\n";
        if (condition) {
            // do stuff
            std::cout << "thread working\n";
            condition = false;
            std::cout << "thread: " << (condition ? "true" : "false") << "\n";
        }
    }
}
```

The thread function loses the lock very shortly when reentering the loop. This allows the main thread to call `cv.notify_one()` while no one is waiting.

Comment: A "spurious" wake up can happen in cv.wait(lock), that is, wake up which is not caused by notify_one() nor notify_all(). cv.wait() DOES NOT wait for mutex, it waits for notify_one() or notify_all(). It uses mutex just for thread safe inner workings and checking the condition variable. Anyway, the whole program makes no sense whatsoever, it has two infinite loops dependent on each other without any pause nor work to do inside any of the loops. I guess that CPU core on which this is running is at 100% during execution.

Comment: @BJovke Here you are absolutely right, it does matter, because the condition is not checked before, or after, the wait.

Comment: @Alan Strokes The condition is checked after the wait, so a spurious wake-up shouldn't cause any problems here.

Comment: Ah, good point. But it's not checked before the first `wait`, which means you could block if the notify happens before the thread gets started (before the lock is ever acquired).

Answer (score 1):

The canonical way to wait involves testing the condition, which would resolve your problem:

```
while (!condition) cv.wait(lock);
```

See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable/wait.

Comment: Wrong, it should be cv.wait(lock, []{ return condition; }); . When you are testing condition like this it's not thread safe unless condition is atomic variable.

Comment: @BJovke Nonsense. The two are exactly equivalent (see the link I posted). The lock is held in both cases except while the wait is in progress.

Comment: Nope. You check the link you posted: "wait causes the current thread to block until the condition variable is notified or a **spurious** wakeup occurs". That means that wake up can happen without notify_one() or notify_all(). Check this: [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spurious_wakeup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spurious_wakeup). On the link you posted it is just shown how the condition_variable is working internally. Before that it assumes that the lock on provided mutex is already acquired, that's how the check is thread safe, yours is not.

Comment: @BJovke How is that relevant? After a spurious wake the lock is re-acquired, the condition is checked, then we go back to waiting with the lock released again. This behaviour is identical in both cases. The key words you are missing are "equivalent to".

Comment: `condition_variable` is not meant to be used this way. The second parameter is there for purpose, to use it, not to create duplicate code to standard library.On your link it is shown how `condition_variable` works _inside_. Look at the bottom of page for usage example.

Comment: @BJovke There are two overloads, one with one parameter where you have to do the loop yourself, and one with two parameters where it does the loop for you. They are exactly equivalent. For a simple condition like we have here I prefer the former; for a more complex predicate I would use the second. But this is a matter of taste, not correctness, because **they are specified to be exactly equivalent**.

Comment: The initial idea of designers of C++11 was to have only first version with one parameter. The second one was introduced only because both on Linux and Windows a spurious wake up can occur due to inner workings of OS's scheduler which cannot be avoided. The first one you would use in loops where it's not of importance if wake up happens by itself sometimes, for example if you are checking for new files or messages. But if you have a loop which increments some counter or performs any incremental action then second version is a must.